# require contact role for opportunities

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, community

How to make contact role required for all the opportunity.
I need to write testclass, trigger and class for the same.

Please help me on the same.

Comment: Why do you think you need a testclass, trigger and class to make the contact role required for all opps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general approach

1. Override the New Opportunity button with a VF page
2. The VF page presents the fields required to create an Opportunity plus a list of existing Contacts on the Account and the ability to add a new Contact
3. The save() action on the VF controller verifies that the user selected one or more of the existing/new contacts as opportunity contact roles and then saves the Opportunity, creates a Contact if entered as new, and inserts OpportunityContactRoles as required between Contact and Opportunity

More interesting issues come in when you want to prevent deletion of the last OCR for a given Opportunity. There is no way to invoke a trigger on `OpportunityContactRole' and the act of deleting an OCR doesn't cause a DML action on either Contact or Opportunity.

For a partial workaround to this, [see here](http:////%09Verify%20results:%20End%20User%20Accounts,%20Opportunities,%20OpportunityLineItems,%20Reseller%20Accounts%20(TBD))

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your eventual use of "Contact Role", you could switch to using lookups on the Opportunity object.  I've done this for many orgs in the past, really simplifies things overall, judgement call for you.  Apps like Docusign can still reference these lookups with customization.

Create lookups to Contact object on the Opportunity object.  They might be called "Decision Maker", "Accounting" etc. Put these on the page layout.

Create a validation rule that checks for the values in these, sending errors as needed.  To have the validation skipped for lead conversion, do this: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008woRIAQ